# Pendant for Nested Styles (like CSS) in Silverlight instead of WPF

Tags: c#, css, silverlight

My task is to set on each Button which is nested in every StackPanel a margin of 20px.

In WPF I use this piece of code in Application.Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
    </Style>
  </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

In Silverlight there is missing the "Style.Resources"-Tag. But I tried this code:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
  <Setter Property="Resources">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Sadly on Silverlight side is nothing happened (no error, no result).

Has anyone an idea if in Silverlight this behavior is possibly without set the Style by key on each Stackpanel manualy?

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight what can't be done simply, can be done using attached dependency properties.
Here is such property, that do what you want - adds entries to elements ResourceDictionaries.

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1.Assets
{
    public class Utils : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalResourcesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AdditionalResources", typeof(ResourceDictionary), typeof(Utils), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnAdditionalResourcesPropertyChanged));

        public static ResourceDictionary GetAdditionalResources(FrameworkElement obj)
        {
            return (ResourceDictionary)obj.GetValue(AdditionalResourcesProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAdditionalResources(FrameworkElement obj, ResourceDictionary value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(AdditionalResourcesProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnAdditionalResourcesPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (element == null)
                return;

            ResourceDictionary oldValue = e.OldValue as ResourceDictionary;
            if (oldValue != null)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in oldValue)
                {
                    if (element.Resources.Contains(entry.Key) && element.Resources[entry.Key] == entry.Value)
                        element.Resources.Remove(entry.Key);
                }
            }

            ResourceDictionary newValue = e.NewValue as ResourceDictionary;
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in newValue)
                {
                    element.Resources.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage of it is very similar to what you have already tried:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="assets:Utils.AdditionalResources">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```